# textbox only for integer in window application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, textbox

I have a Windows application, in which there is a login form and registration form.
In the registration form there are 4 `textbox`es in which one of them is for getting the user contact number (Mobile Number), where only numbers are allowed.
I want that user can enter only `integer` number not `char` just like in `asp` application, where using `ajax` textfilter we restrict the user to enter only integer number.

Does this type of functionality exist, such that the Windows application can restrict the user?

Comment: have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1)You can handle the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and make sure that no key other than the digits(0-9) are displayed in the `TextBox`.
You can use `Regex` to check whether the text contains letters or not.

Another option is to validate input of text before processing the text, if it contains characters other than numbers, issue a warning to the user and allow him to change the text of the `TextBox`.

```
     private void Text_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e )
     {
        if(!char.isDigit(textBox1.Text[textBox1.Text.Length-1]))
        {
             string temp = string.SubString(textBox1.Text, 0, textBox1.Text.Length-1) ;
             textBox1.Text = temp ; 
        }
     }
```

WORKING:-
Every time the text changes, it checks the last character added and if it's not a digit then,it doesn't display it.
For eg if after entering 971 I enter r then the `if` condition becomes true and the `Text` field of `TextBox` resets the text to 971 and doesn't display the "r".

2)Otherwise, you can use a `MaskedTextBox`
[image] 
Change the masked property of maskedTextBox to Digits like this:-
[image]

Check the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666932/Using-Masked-TextBox-in-NET
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1534/Masked-C-TextBox-Control

3)OPTION-3:- You can create a custom control after deriving from the `TextBox` class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.90).aspx